# IPython Notebook with ScipySuperpack: missing markupsafe dependency

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

On a Mac OSX 10.8.4. I installed IPython via ScipySuperpack. It seemed to install fine.

To launch I was told to input `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` in the command line.

However I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==1.0.0-dev', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 538, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 309, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 361, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 304, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 468, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 400, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-1.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg/jinja2/nodes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg/jinja2/utils.py", line 520, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode ImportError: No module named markupsafe
```

Suggestions on where I went wrong?

Comment: `pip install markupsafe`? I guess the ScipySuperpack just hasn't been updated to include that.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem in my newly installed ubuntu 14.04

It seems like the pip install jinja2 has gone wrong, the solution for me is

```
pip uninstall jinja2
sudo apt-get install python-jinja2
```

Comment: it works but in my case i had to do `pip install jinja2`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after installing jupyter via `pip install jupyter`. The solution that worked for me was to download the markupsafe tarball directly from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe and instal via `sudo python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pip version of your ScipySuperpack installation, do

```
pip install ipython[all]
```

This should fix all dependencies.

Comment: Same error. Under install I get an error:    'running install_egg_info

Copying Sphinx.egg-info to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg-info

running install_scripts

Installing sphinx-apidoc script to /usr/local/bin

error: /usr/local/bin/sphinx-apidoc: Permission denied'

Comment: @mylesg: Try again as root, i.e. `sudo pip install ipython[all]`.

Comment: Appreciate your support. Did the above. Asked for password (gave it), then seems to install. When I input `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` Now back to the same error listed in my original problem with  `from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode ImportError: No module named markupsafe`

Comment: Strange. What happens when you do an explicit `sudo pip install markupsafe`? Do `which pip` and `which ipython` point to the same folder?

Comment: hmm. I get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.18-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...`

Comment: What about the output of `which pip` and `which ipython`? Can you import markupsafe from the ipython shell? Finally, try `sudo pip install --upgrade ipython[all]`.

Comment: I believe that your issue is that you have several Python installations (your system installation, the ScipySuperpack installation etc.) on your computer. So if you want to use IPython you have to choose among your installations. The same for updates via pip. Each pip version will only install packages for a specific installation on your system. So if you want to fix your ScipySuperpack installation you have to work on *that* installation...

Comment: Also this isn't the right place for this kind of discussion. Write me a message or please look for help elsewhere.